# PyCharm Jupyter notebook print() shows after input()

Tags: python, input, jupyter-notebook, pycharm

In PyCharm's Jupyter notebook I would have a code such as:

```
print("apple, orange, cherry")
fruit = input("Enter a fruit from the list")
```

input statement will show first and after inputting a fruit, the print statement will show up after. Essentially, a user wouldn't know which fruit to input because it doesn't show up till after the input statement.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `print` statement to:

```
print("apple, orange, cherry", flush=True)
```

and it should show up before the `input` statement.

Comment: not for me, have it in a while True loop